# fwrite() function gives a file with a lot of ugly symbols

Tags: matlab, fwrite

```
fid = fopen('stressVStime.txt','w');
format long;
timeaxis = zeros([1,1000]);
stress = zeros([1,1000]);
for n=1:1000
    some codes of calculation here...
    fwrite(fid, [timeaxis(n), stress(n)], 'float64');
end
fclose(fid);
```

Basically I am wanting to write the vectors `timeaxis` and `stress`, which are all numbers, into a file using `fwrite()` function in Matlab. When I ran the above codes, no error is reported but when I look at the file, they are not numbers but are all ugly symbols in a total mess. Am I using `fwrite` correctly? How should I fix this problem?

I use `format long` because I need some high precision.

Answer (score 3):

By using `fwrite` you are writing the numbers to the file *as binary* meaning that a normal text editor will not display this properly.

Rather than using `fwrite`, consider using `fprintf` to write the data out to the file in human-readable ASCII format. The `%f` format specifier indicates that the input is going to be floating-point numbers.

```
fid = fopen('stressVStime.txt','w');
fprintf(fid, '%f %f\n', [timeaxis; stress])
fclose(fid)
```

As a side note, `format long` has *no* effect on the output to a file, just how a number is displayed in the MATLAB command window.